# How does Apache process several requests at a time?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, multi-threading

If 10 requests hit Apache, does it process them one by one, so when R3 finishes, then it starts to run R4, or does it fire 10 processes/threads/whatever and are resolved simultaneously?

Now some background: I have a PHP script that takes up to two minutes to do some processes. My question is: while a client is waiting for this 2 minutes, all the other clients requests are being processed? Or also waiting for this one to end?

By the way, **if there are simultaneous request, how can I handle them?** Let's say put a limit on them. Or a limit on resources consumed. For instance I want the server to use its 80% performance on serving the webapp, and just a 20% for those long operations, because I have no hurry to end them.

I don't know if it matters, but is all in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server handles requests concurrently up to a limit which you set in the configuration file. Have a look at these directives:

```
MinSpareThreads
MaxSpareThreads
ThreadsPerChild
MaxClients
MaxRequestsPerChild
```

Comment: Thanks! How about setting resources limits, is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: I think you're looking for`RLimitCPU`and `RLimitMEM`